# Why do attackers always face the Imperial blockade head on?

Tags: star-wars

In Star Wars when ships exit hyperspace they face the Imperial blockade. Would it not be easier to stay out of the blockade's range, go around the planet and access the planet through the other side?

Comment: They use thrusters? Or completely surround the planet.

Comment: Who says they aren't in orbit...just a big one?

Comment: @Paulie_D Actually they are just logical progression. If you always come out on the same side of a planet (that is orbiting a star usually) then how does a fleet always end up between the planet and the hyperspace exit point? Under constant power to maintain position between? The problem is the question is at the same time asking about he fleet orbiting AND assuming the fleet is holding a position over one face of the planet.

Comment: @Joshua, Read the above.

Comment: your assuming the blockade is not around the entire planet. we only SEE the part directly in front of the planet.

Comment: Maybe it's more a result of the mechanics of hyperspace "lanes" being sort of fixed? But doesn't explain why you can't exit elsewhere in the system and approach from the other side. Keep in mind there is a conscious and willful lack of spacial/physical realism and resulting strategy in star wars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new (canon) [Tarkin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tarkin_(novel)) novel gives a pretty solid explanation of how hyperspace works.

There are two key elements to a successful hyperspace flight; **avoiding large gravity wells** (which will drag you out of hyperspace with catastrophic results, assuming you don't just plough straight into them) and **avoiding interstellar objects large enough to cause shield failure** (with the same spectacular results) by means of sticking to known hyperspace corridors that are either naturally clear of obstacles, or which have been swept at great expense.

The consequence of this is that **there are only a very limited number of places, and hence directions, from which you can enter a star system without risking going splat.** In relatively unexplored systems like Endor and Yavin, the number of entry points might only be one which means that interdicting them is a pretty simple matter.

> *Rancit blinked and stood tall. “My lord, we are simply attempting to
>   safeguard our interests in those systems. Given the path the
>   dissidents have pursued, it is — that is, **we think it reasonable to
>   assume that they are intent on targeting systems in the Inner Rim,
>   from which potential hyperspace jump points and destinations will
>   multiply beyond measure.** We have taken the liberty of declaring some
>   key systems no-entry zones, but the need to allocate resources to
>   other systems grows only more complicated.”*

and

> *Tarkin ground his teeth. The situation was growing worse by the
>   moment. In star systems lacking nearby hyperspace relay stations, a
>   ship’s pilot had to navigate by beacon or buoy, unless the ship was
>   equipped with a sophisticated navicomputer of the sort the Carrion
>   Spike boasted, which could plot jumps well beyond the next beacon, all
>   the way to the Core if necessary. **According to the Predator’s inferior
>   device, the Murkhana system had no fewer than a dozen jump egresses,
>   and most of those were into other Outer Rim systems where beacons were
>   still more plentiful than hyperspace relay stations.***